# Adding a default value to text-input in simple-form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I want to add a default value to a text-input field using simple-form.
With `:placeholder` it is not used as default....

```
<%= f.input :user, :placeholder => 'user@example.com' %>
```

Comment: to have default value and also keep actual value in field (for example user's email) try like this --- f.input :user, input_html: { value: @user.email.present? ? @user.email : 'example@domain.com' }. Also its new more readable syntax in RoR

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
<%= f.input :user, :input_html => { :value => 'user@example.com' } %>
```

Comment: Maybe, `:input_html => { :value => 'user@domain.com' }`

Comment: Yes, realized that too. Fixed it.

Answer (score 11):

You can simply do:

```
<% f.text_field, value: 'user@example.com' %>
```

`text_field` is good if you are working with form search gem like Ransack.

Comment: I think if you do not use the :input_html option and simply use :value or value: then that value will be reset to the default each time you return to the edit page.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in the controller and keep data details out of your forms.  Instead of this:

`def new
  @article = Article.new
end`

you can do this:

`def new
  # hardcode default values (as shown) or generate on the fly
  @article = Article.new(title: "10 Best Things")
end`

The "new" form will open with the default (pre-set) values filled in.  This should work with simple-form, plain old Rails, or any other form generator that does does things the Rails way..

Answer (score 1):

On rails 5.1 `placeholder: 'aaaaaaaaaaa'` works. E.g.

```
<%= f.input :user, :placeholder => 'user@example.com' %>
```

will work on rails 5.1

Answer (score 1):

You can try this option:

```
<%= f.input :user, label: 'user@example.com' %>
```