# Keep data on the field after submit a form with error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

After validation, I got error and return back to :action => :new. Some field on form already filled, so I want to keep them filled after error message too. How it can be done?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about ruby. But in php, when you are making the form you can use a variable for the "default" value. When the form is first called, it would be null or "", when it is used for an error it will have the text that the user put in.

Comment: Thx RandelI, but with default value, it's not works. How can i do it in rails?

Comment: Just found a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871827/adding-a-default-value-to-text-input sorry for the formatting this is from my iPhone. Anyways I think you can replace the text with the value of the user inputted.