# Rails Simple Form Default Value if Submitted Nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I need to overwrite any blank field submissions in my simple form with the text value "N/A".  I've found how to set a default value beforehand, but I would like the field left blank for users to fill out and submit, and only changed if they leave it blank.  Is this possible?  Thanks!

Comment: what is your model like and how are you handling the submitted values now?

Comment: Also take a look at this (possible duplicate) question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871827/adding-a-default-value-to-text-input-in-simple-form
And this blog post: https://www.flipflops.org/2013/02/12/default-form-values-in-rails/

Comment: Yea, I was able to get that link content working, but it creates a default value before submitting, not after.  

Currently '<%= f.input :survey_year %>' is the field format. I then call these in a table grid to be displayed.  I need the "N/A" value so when they're called, they don't just appear blank.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= f.input :survey_year, :input_html => { :value => 'N/A'} %>
```

Should do the trick.  See the flipflops.org link in my comment above for alternative approaches.

Comment: Unfortunately that pre-populates the field with "N/A", doesn't it change it to "N/A" after its submitted, like I need.  That will definitely come in handy for some other situations though, so I appreciate the response!

Comment: What does your model look like?  You should be able to set a default value in the model that has nothing to do with the view but that gets overwritten on submit of the form.  You could also deal with this on the view of the table grid (a very confusing phrase as tables and grids are distinct concepts in layout) by something like <%= if myField.nil? then "N/A" else myField %>.

Comment: Right, currently the fields look like this:
<%= @ship.hull.try(:name) || "N/A" %>, and do exactly what you're describing, but I was advised to try and set a default value on submission, rather than when they're called.  Any advice on how to set a default value in the model?  That sounds like my best case solution.  Thanks!

Comment: See the first method described in the flipflops link: https://www.flipflops.org/2013/02/12/default-form-values-in-rails/

Answer (score 1):

Try to the following

```
before_save :default_values

def default_values
    self.name ||= 'N/A' #=> note self.name = 'N/A' if self.name.nil?
end
```

When a user submits a form with `blank/nil` name then it will submit to `"N/A"` otherwise none

Comment: Thanks! Where would I put this? If it isn't obvious already, I'm still getting my head around rails.

Comment: To your model which you used for `name` purpose

Comment: If your model is `User ` then use this inside `User ` class